# Should I implement revisioning using database triggers or using django-reversion?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, architecture

We're looking into implementing audit logs in our application and we're not sure how to do it correctly.
I know that django-reversion works and works well but there's a cost of using it.
The web server will have to make two roundtrips to the database when saving a record even if the save is in the same transaction because at least in postgres the changes are written to the database and comitting the transaction makes the changes visible.
So this will block the web server until the revision is saved to the database if we're not using async I/O which is currently the case. Even if we would use async I/O generating the revision's data takes CPU time which again blocks the web server from handling other requests.

We can use database triggers instead but our DBA claims that offloading this sort of work to the database will use resources that are meant for handling more transactions.
Is using database triggers for this sort of work a bad idea?

We can scale both the web servers using a load balancer and the database using read/write replicas.
Are there any tradeoffs we're missing here?
What would help us decide?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the pattern of db usage in your website.

Which may be unique to you, however most web apps *read* much more often than they *write* to the db.  In fact it's fairly common to see optimisations done, to help scaling a web app, which trade off more complicated 'save' operations to get faster reads. An example would be [denormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) where some data from related records is copied to the parent record on each save so as to avoid repeatedly doing complicated aggregate/join queries.

This is just an example, but unless you know your specific situation is different I'd say don't worry about doing a bit of extra work on save.

One caveat would be to consider excluding some models from the revisioning system.  For example  if you are using Django db-backed sessions, the session records are saved on every request. You'd want to avoid doing unnecessary work there.

As for doing it via triggers vs Django app... I think the main considerations here are not to do with performance:

- Django app solution is more 'obvious' and 'maintainable'... the app will be in your pip requirements file and Django INSTALLED_APPS, it's obvious to other developers that it's there and working and doesn't need someone to remember to run the custom SQL on the db server when you move to a new server
- With a db trigger solution you can be certain it will run whenever a record is changed *by any means*... whereas with Django app, anyone changing records via a psql console will bypass it. Even in the Django ORM, certain bulk operations bypass the model save method/save signals. Sometimes this is desirable however.

Another thing I'd point out is that your production webserver will be multiprocess/multithreaded... so although, yes, a lengthy db write will block the webserver it will only block the *current process*. Your webserver will have other processes which are able to server other requests concurrently. So it won't block the whole webserver.

So again, unless you have a pattern of usage where you anticipate a high frequency of *concurrent writes* to the db, I'd say probably don't worry about it.

Comment: Our REST API has indeed a higher rate of reads then writes but our backend services are the opposite. They write at least 90% of the time. One of our backend services constantly writes data and the data should be revisioned which is why I'm worried about performance.

Comment: well, then I guess triggers may be a bit more efficient on the db side since they'll run without having to send additional queries over a client connection

Comment: Will database triggers scale better then django-reversion? Why?